# c# hook in console application Application.Run() vs. Application.Run(new Form())

Tags: c#, hook

I tested a simple WH_KEYBOARD hook in a console application. Because in a console application I have no message loop I tried Application.Run(). This doesn't work. If I use Application.Run(new Form()); it works and the keys will be captured. I dont' understand why Application.Run() allone is not sufficient.

```
hookID = SetWindowsHookEx((int)WH_TYPE.WH_KEYBOARD, hp, (IntPtr)null,     GetCurrentThreadId());

      Console.WriteLine("HookID ist {0}",hookID);
      // Works but Application.Run(); alone wouldn't work
      Application.Run(new Form());
```

Comment: The form class is what provides the message loop. Without a message loop you won't be capturing Windows messages.

Comment: But Application.Run() allone should also work and it doesn't. MSDN says to Application.Run(): "Begins running a standard application message loop on the current thread." https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.application.run(v=vs.110).aspx  So why Application.Run doesn't work für WH_KEYBOARD?

Comment: From the MSDN article for Application.Run(): Most Windows Forms developers will not need to use this version of the method. You should use the Run(Form) overload to start an application with a main form, so that the application terminates when the main form is closed. For all other situations, use the Run(ApplicationContext) overload, which supports supplying an ApplicationContext object for better control over the lifetime of the application. It doesn't explicitly say that Application.Run() won't work, it just says not to use it use Application.Run(ApplicationContext) instead.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for you answer. But my question is why Application.Run() won't work and Application.Run(new Form()) does. So maybe someone has an idea... Because I only need the message loop to bring my hook in the console application to work.